# Twitter Poll Votes Number Fetching

Tags: twitter, polling

Can someone please explain or show a method how to fetch the number of votes in a poll. Like if there is 3 options, how many no of votes each option is having instead of % for each option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not give that information, sorry.

> Does not include vote information or poll results
>   https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/enrichments/overview/poll-metadata